# How to exchange data between devices in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Imagine a Flutter app that's running on Android, iOS, Windows and MacOSX:

How can you exchange data between devices if there's no internet connection available? (Lan or Bluetooth would be OK though, just no internet) What options are available? How would you tackle that requirement?

Any advise is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Server and client configuration on local network! check `HttpServer` `HttpClient` in dart